# Is it possible to have macOS - Finder remember your column customizations?

Tags: macos, finder

I don't need certain columns so I remove them from the display that Finder has.

However, once I close and open Finder again, the columns come back and I have to remove them again.

This is macOS - Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

Finder remembers window layouts & details on a per window/per view type basis, meaning that setting defaults once you've been working on it a while can be a bit tricky.

If you select one window you're happy with the layout on, then you can use "Show View Options" - View Menu or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  to set your current layout as default...

[image]

However, this will not override any windows that have already been opened, only brand new window views.

One way to attempt to clear all previously stored views is by removing the associated invisible [.DS_Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) files.
Stack Overflow has a method using the Terminal - [Delete .DS_STORE files in current folder and all subfolders from command line on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483670/delete-ds-store-files-in-current-folder-and-all-subfolders-from-command-line-on) There are also paid apps, Like CleanMyMac which can do the task, though I don't know of a free one. [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) [freeware] used to be able to do it, but it seems to be missing from the Mojave version. Onyx versions are tied to each macOS version, so if you're on an older macOS it might be worth a look.